# How is it possible to call methods of Enumeration

Tags: java, enumeration

[Enumeration API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html#hasMoreElements())

In the example given in the Enumeration API there is the following example:

```
for (Enumeration<E> e = v.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();)
   System.out.println(e.nextElement());
```

But how can you call those methods on the elements of the vector while Enumeration is an iterface?
I mean these methods have no body (implementation)?

Comment: v.elements() returns something that implements Enumeration. Print e.getClass().getName()

Comment: @SameerNaik You are 90% true. But in this case, it's anonymous inner class.

Comment: Its just the way they implemented it as per answer from Suresh. But it is a concrete class that implements all the interface methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Enumeration<E> e = v.elements();
```

That means `elements()` method returns a class that implements `Enumeration` or returns an `annonymous innerclass` of that instance.

Here is the source code of `Vector` classes `elements()` method

```
 public Enumeration<E> More ...elements() {
312         return new Enumeration<E>() {
313             int count = 0;
314 
315             public boolean More ...hasMoreElements() {
316                 return count < elementCount;
317             }
318 
319             public E More ...nextElement() {
320                 synchronized (Vector.this) {
321                     if (count < elementCount) {
322                         return elementData(count++);
323                     }
324                 }
325                 throw new NoSuchElementException("Vector Enumeration");
326             }
327         };
328     }
```

If you see it's returning `return new Enumeration<E>() {`

Comment: Where can you find implementations of methods which are from standard Java classes

Comment: @J.Newb There are multiple ways to get and read source code. But one I follow is GrepCode.  

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Vector.java